# Undefined link function in gamma distribution

Tags: generalized-linear-model, fitting, link-function

The nonlinear  model I am fitting  gamma distribution with inverse or log is not converging. There is one observation having zero value in the response variable. Does this zero affects to model the data? Any answer warmly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried dropping that zero from the analysis?  I don't think zero is a part of the gamma distribution.  Also: are you really sure it's zero, and not just very, very small?

Comment: @Matt Dropping a zero is usually not a good idea unless the dataset is so large that losing an extreme value will make no difference in the analysis.  Your implicit suggestion of treating it as very small is good, but then the result can be sensitive to the value chosen.  One could check for that in various ways.  A more formal approach is to treat the zero as a left-censored value (censored perhaps at the second lowest value) and use methods that handle censored or interval-valued data (which includes ML).

Comment: @whuber converted your comment to cw answer - question very old and unlikely a better answer is possible

Comment: @Corone Thanks: that is a good way to handle it.  I appreciate your efforts at achieving closure for some of our unanswered questions!

Answer (score 5):

Dropping a zero is usually not a good idea unless the dataset is so large that losing an extreme value will make no difference in the analysis. Treating it as very small is good, but then the result can be sensitive to the value chosen. One could check for that in various ways. A more formal approach is to treat the zero as a left-censored value (censored perhaps at the second lowest value) and use methods that handle censored or interval-valued data (which includes ML)